# Solver CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING is not reaching the optimal result

Tags: python, or-tools

## Problem

I'm implementing a generalized assignment problem using LINGO (in which I have experience to model mathematical problems) and Or-tools, but results were different.

## Brief explanation of my assignment problem

I have a set of houses (called 'object' in the model) that need to be build. Each house needs a set of resources. To supply these resources, there are 3 suppliers. The resource cost varies by supplier.

The model should assign those suppliers to the houses in order to minimize the total cost of assignments.

## Model

**Parameters**

- ***resource_cost_per_supplier[i,j]***:  cost of resource *i* of supplier *j*.
- ***resource_cost_factor_per_object[i,j]***: matrix that signals the resources demanded by the objects (cost factor > 0). In addition, it contains the cost factor of resource *i* demanded by object *j*. This factor is calculated based on the duration of use of the resource during the construction of the object and also in others contractual factors.
- ***supplier_budget_limit[j]***: supplier budget limit of supplier *j*. Each supplier has a budget limit that should not be exceded (it's in the contract).
- ***supplier_budget_tolerance_margin_limit[j]***: supplier budget tolerance margin limit of supplier *j*. To the model works, I had to create this tolerance margin, that is applied in the supplier budget limit to create an acceptable range of supplier cost.
- ***object_demand_attended_per_supplier[i,j]***: binary matrix that signals if the supplier *i* has all the resources required by object *j*.

**Variables**

- ***x[i,j]***: binary variable that indicate if the supplier *i* will be (1) or not (0) assigned to the object *j*.
- ***supplier_cost[j]***: variable that represents the cost of supplier *j* in the market share. Its value is given by:
  [image: img1]
- ***total_cost***: variable that represents the total cost of market share. Its value is given by:
  [image: img2]

**Objective function**

*min Z = total_cost*

**Constraints**

**1** - Ensure that each object ***j*** will have only one supplier ***i***.

[image: img3]

**2** - For each supplier ***i***, the sum of the cost of all your assignments must be greater than or equal to your budget limit minus the tolerance margin.

[image: img4]

**3** - For each supplier *j*, the sum of the cost of all your assignments must be less than or equal to your budget limit plus the tolerance margin.

[image: img5]

**4** - Ensure that a supplier ***i*** will not assigned to an object ***j*** if the supplier ***i*** cannot provide all the resources of object ***j***.

[image: img6]

**5** - Ensure that variable *x* is binary for every supplier *i* and object *j*.

[image: img7]

## Code

**Or-tools (Python)**

```
from __future__ import print_function
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
import pandas as pd
import numpy

###### [START] parameters ######
num_objects = 252 #Number of objects
num_resources = 35 #Number of resources (not every object will use all resources. It depends of the type of the object and other things) 
num_suppliers = 3 #Number of suppliers
resource_cost_per_supplier = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hrassis/divisao-mercado/master/input_prototype/resource_cost_per_supplier.csv', index_col = 0).to_numpy()
resource_cost_factor_per_object = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hrassis/divisao-mercado/master/input_prototype/resource_cost_factor_per_object.csv', index_col = 0).to_numpy()
object_demand_attended_per_supplier = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hrassis/divisao-mercado/master/input_prototype/object_demand_attended_per_supplier.csv', index_col = 0).to_numpy()
supplier_budget_limit = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hrassis/divisao-mercado/master/input_prototype/supplier_budget_limit.csv', index_col = 0)['budget_limit'].values
supplier_budget_tolerance_margin_limit = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hrassis/divisao-mercado/master/input_prototype/supplier_budget_tolerance_margin_limit.csv', index_col = 0)['tolerance_margin'].values
###### [END] parameters ######

###### [START] variables ######
#Assignment variable
x = {}

supplier_cost = []

#Total cost of market share
total_cost = 0

###### [END] variables ######

def main():
  #Declare the solver
  solver = pywraplp.Solver('GeneralizedAssignmentProblem', pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)

  #Assignment variable
  #x = {}

  #Ensure that the assignment variable is binary
  for i in range(num_suppliers):
      for j in range(num_objects):
        x[i, j] = solver.BoolVar('x[%i,%i]' % (i,j))

  #Assigning an expression to each supplier_cost element
  for j in range(num_suppliers):
    supplier_cost.append(solver.Sum(solver.Sum(resource_cost_per_supplier[i,j] * resource_cost_factor_per_object[i,k] * x[j,k] for k in range(num_objects)) for i in range(num_resources)))

  #Total cost of market share
  total_cost = solver.Sum(supplier_cost[j] for j in range(num_suppliers))

  #Objective function
  solver.Minimize(total_cost)

  ###### [START] constraints ######
  # 1 - Ensure that each object will have only one supplier
  for j in range(num_objects):
    solver.Add(solver.Sum([x[i,j] for i in range(num_suppliers)]) == 1)

  # 2 - For each supplier j, the sum of the cost of all your allocations must be greater than or equal to your budget limit minus the tolerance margin
  for j in range(num_suppliers):
    solver.Add(supplier_cost[j] >= total_cost * (supplier_budget_limit[j] - supplier_budget_tolerance_margin_limit[j]))

  # 3 - For each supplier j, the sum of the cost of all your allocations must be less than or equal to your budget limit plus the tolerance margin
  for j in range(num_suppliers):
    solver.Add(supplier_cost[j] <= total_cost * (supplier_budget_limit[j] + supplier_budget_tolerance_margin_limit[j]))

  # 4 - Ensure that a supplier i will not assigned to an object j if the supplier i can not supply all resources demanded by object j
  for i in range(num_suppliers):
      for j in range(num_objects):
        solver.Add(x[i,j] - object_demand_attended_per_supplier[i,j] <= 0)

  ###### [END] constraints ######

  solution = solver.Solve()

  #Print the result
  if solution == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
    print('------- Solution -------')
    print('Total cost =', round(total_cost.solution_value(), 2))
    for i in range(num_suppliers):
      print('-----')
      print('Supplier', i)
      print('-> cost:', round(supplier_cost[i].solution_value(), 2))
      print('-> cost percentage:', format(supplier_cost[i].solution_value()/total_cost.solution_value(),'.2%'))
      print('-> supplier budget limit:', format(supplier_budget_limit[i], '.0%'))
      print('-> supplier budget tolerance margin limit:', format(supplier_budget_tolerance_margin_limit[i], '.0%'))
      print('-> acceptable range: {0} <= cost percentage <= {1}'.format(format(supplier_budget_limit[i] - supplier_budget_tolerance_margin_limit[i], '.0%'), format(supplier_budget_limit[i] + supplier_budget_tolerance_margin_limit[i], '.0%'))) 
      # print('-> objects: {0}'.format(i))
  else:
    print('The problem does not have an optimal solution.')

  #Generate a result to consult
  assignment_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['object','supplier','cost','assigned'])

  for i in range(num_suppliers):
    for j in range(num_objects):
      assignment_result = assignment_result.append({'object': j, 'supplier': i, 'cost': get_object_cost(j, i), 'assigned': x[i, j].solution_value()}, ignore_index=True)
  assignment_result.to_excel('assignment_result.xlsx')


def get_object_cost(object_index, supplier_index):

  object_cost = 0.0

  for i in range(num_resources):
    object_cost = object_cost + resource_cost_factor_per_object[i,object_index] * resource_cost_per_supplier[i,supplier_index]

  return object_cost

#Run main
main()
```

**LINGO**

```
model:
    title: LINGO;

    data:
        !Number of objects;
        num_objects = @OLE('LINGO_input.xlsx',num_objects);

        !Number of resources (not every object will use all resources. It depends of the type of the object and other things);
        num_resources = @OLE('LINGO_input.xlsx',num_resources);

        !Number of suppliers;
        num_suppliers = @OLE('LINGO_input.xlsx',num_suppliers);
    enddata

    sets:
        suppliers/1..num_suppliers/:supplier_budget_limit,supplier_tolerance_margin_limit,supplier_cost;
        resources/1..num_resources/:;
        objects/1..num_objects/:;

        resources_suppliers(resources,suppliers):resource_cost_per_supplier;
        resources_objects(resources,objects):resource_cost_factor_per_object;
        suppliers_objects(suppliers,objects):x,object_demand_attended_supplier;
    endsets

    data:
        resource_cost_per_supplier = @OLE('LINGO_input.xlsx',resource_cost_per_supplier[cost]);
        resource_cost_factor_per_object = @OLE('LINGO_input.xlsx',resource_cost_factor_per_object[cost_factor]);
        supplier_budget_limit = @OLE('LINGO_input.xlsx',supplier_budget_limit[budget_limit_percentage]);
        supplier_tolerance_margin_limit = @OLE('LINGO_input.xlsx',supplier_budget_tolerance_margin_limit[budget_tolerance_percentage]);
        object_demand_attended_supplier = @OLE('LINGO_input.xlsx',object_demand_attended_per_supplier[supply_all_resources]);
    enddata

    !The array 'supplier_cost' was created to store the total cost of each supplier;
    @FOR(suppliers(j):supplier_cost(j)= @SUM(resources(i):@SUM(objects(k):resource_cost_per_supplier(i,j)*resource_cost_factor_per_object(i,k)*x(j,k))));

    !Total cost of market share;
    total_cost = @SUM(suppliers(i):supplier_cost(i));

    !Objective function;
    min = total_cost;

    !Ensure that each object will have only one supplier;
    @FOR(objects(j):@SUM(suppliers(i):x(i,j))=1);

    !For each supplier j, the sum of the cost of all your assignments must be greater than or equal to your budget limit minus the tolerance margin;
    @FOR(suppliers(j):supplier_cost(j) >= total_cost*(supplier_budget_limit(j)-supplier_tolerance_margin_limit(j)));

    !For each supplier j, the sum of the cost of all your assignments must be less than or equal to your budget limit plus the tolerance margin;
    @FOR(suppliers(j):supplier_cost(j) <= total_cost*(supplier_budget_limit(j)+supplier_tolerance_margin_limit(j)));

    !Ensure that a supplier j will not assigned to an object k if the supplier j can not supply all resources demanded by object k;
    @FOR(suppliers(j):@FOR(objects(k):x(j,k)-object_demand_attended_supplier(j,k)<=0));

    !Ensure that the assignment variable is binary;
    @FOR(suppliers(i):@FOR(objects(j):@BIN(x(i,j))));

    data:
        @OLE('LINGO_input.xlsx',output[assigned])=x;        
        @OLE('LINGO_input.xlsx',objective_function_value)=total_cost;       
        @OLE('LINGO_input.xlsx',supplier_cost)=supplier_cost;       
    enddata
```

## Results

The picture below shows the comparative result between Or-Tools and LINGO. I emphasize that the data used by the two implementations were exactly the same and I checked all the data several times.

[image: img8]

Note that there is a difference of 1.876,20 between the two implementations. LINGO, that uses a Branch and Bound algorithm, found a better solution than Or-Tools. The difference is caused by the assignments inconsistencies shown below.

[image: img9]

Regarding the processing time of the algorithms, LINGO took around 14 min and Or-Tools less than 1 min.

All the data used in the two implementations are in this repository: https://github.com/hrassis/divisao-mercado. Data used by LINGO is in folder input_lingo and used by Or-Tools is in the folder input_prototype. In addition I uploaded the validation report.

Answer (score 1):

After "cheating" a bit:

```
solver.Add(x[1, 177] == 1)
solver.Add(x[0, 186] == 1)
solver.Add(x[0, 205] == 1)
solver.Add(x[2, 206] == 1)
solver.Add(x[2, 217] == 1)
solver.Add(x[2, 66] == 1)
solver.Add(x[2, 115] == 1)
solver.Add(x[1, 237] == 1)
```

The solver returns a better objective, so I believe there is a bug either on the CBC binary or the OR-Tools interface to it (sounds like the former).

Can you try using the CP-SAT solver?

There have been quite a few problems with CBC

- https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1450
- https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1525

Comment: I can not use CP-SAT Solver because it is an integer constraint solver and I have float parameters in my constraints.

Comment: You can scale everything up (eg: *1000)

Comment: Thank you @Stradivari, but I think this is not an elegant solution to consider in my master's dissertation. Do you know any other library that I can use? Thank you again.

Comment: Python-mip also uses CBC but looks like it doesnt have those bugs, should be easy to translate your current code to it

Comment: Python-MIP worked. I only had to set some precision parameters to reach the optimal solution, because the object function value was different like or-tools. I supose that I have to do the same in CBC_MIXED (or-tools) solver, but I don't know how can I set up.